# R I would like to record an empty data entry using as.Date

Tags: r, datetime, date-format

R - I would like to input an empty data entry using as.Date. If I enter in the R console as.Date(""), I get NA as a return without any error message.

When I used as.Date() inside a loop, I got an error message to ask me to supply the 'origin'. But when I included the 'origin' argument in the as.Date function, as you can see below, I still get an error message.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any help on this. Many thanks!

```
for (r in 1:nrow(R3)){
  R3$DATE1[r]<-ifelse(
    R3$dateDiff2[r]==R3$MIN[r],
    RR3$DATE1[r],
    as.Date("", origin="1970-01-01")
  )
}
```

<Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: Have you tried converting the origin to date? i.e. `as.Date("", origin=as.Date("1970-01-01"))` But also what are you expecting an empty date to look like, if not NA?

Comment: Thank you very much! Once I converted the origin to date, the problem was solved!